# Pass parameter to PowerPivot query

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a PowerPivot query set up like this:

`exec sp_GetOrders NULL, NULL, '2012-08-01', '2012-09-17', 'All', 0, NULL, 1, 0, NULL`

but I want the date fields to be parameters from a cell. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem possible according to this thread. Really a problem with Powerpivot.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel/thread/b579e218-e4f0-4153-81d1-eac96692d423/